# playwright python: check whether authenticated session is still valid?

Tags: python, authentication, playwright

writing my first playwright code to automate some web routines.

my code will login to a website to do a few things, n sometimes I will login from another device.  this will break my session running.  Is there a way to check?  My code runs in a while loop and never ends.

currently using python n storage_state to avoid login again.

context = browser.new_context(storage_state=auth)
if ( not authenticated ):
login

something like this, but I am not sure which to check.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the way to check.  Apparently if I go to the url which I can access when I am logged in, it will stay in that url.  If not logged in, it will redirect me to the login page.  Now, I just check page.url.